# Cannot store the value of my radio button

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to store the value of the hamburger radio button in $hamburger however it comes up like it hasn't been stored and won't go into hamburger = 'yes' and i don't know why for php and html.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" >

<p><input type = 'radio' name = 'Hamburger' value "yes" />yes </p>
<p><input type = 'radio' name = 'Hamburger' value "no" /> no</p>
<input type = "hidden" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
<p><input type="submit"  value="submit" name ="submit1 " " /></p> 
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['Hamburger']))
                            {

                                $hamburger = trim($_POST['Hamburger']);
                                echo $hamburger;

                            if($hamburger == 'yes')
                            {


                            }
                            </form>
```

Comment: simple: no form tags and post method.

Comment: another thing; missing equal signs.

Comment: I had that in my code just forgot to post it

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer if you already saw it before the edit. There were a few other things I spotted. the answer works. reload it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, both of your value(s) are missing equal signs

```
<p><input type = 'radio' name = 'Hamburger' value "yes" />yes </p>
                                                 ^
<p><input type = 'radio' name = 'Hamburger' value "no" /> no</p>
                                                 ^
```

which is why it doesn't recognize it "equaling" something.

Plus, you need to put your closing `</form>` tag above your PHP and inside HTML.

Rewrite: and there was a missing closing brace `}` which would have thrown a parse error, had error reporting been enabled on your server.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

<p><input type = 'radio' name = 'Hamburger' value = "yes" />yes </p>
<p><input type = 'radio' name = 'Hamburger' value = "no" /> no</p>
<input type = "hidden" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
<p><input type="submit"  value="submit" name ="submit1 " " /></p>

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Hamburger']))
    {

        $hamburger = trim($_POST['Hamburger']);
        echo $hamburger;

    if($hamburger == 'yes')
    {

      // do something
    }

} // added the missing closing brace
```

Sidenote:

`trim` in `trim($_POST['Hamburger']` is redundant, since it's a radio and not a text input.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.\

Comment: @javascripthelp You're welcome. Glad to have been of help, *cheers*